# NTP synchroinzation waiting for a while after booting

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, ntp

According to the recommendation on Arch Wiki, I set my hardware clock to UTC. And here is the result of `timedatectl status` on my machine when just booted:

```
      Local time: Tue 2013-07-02 15:38:03 CST
  Universal time: Tue 2013-07-02 07:38:03 UTC
        Timezone: Asia/Shanghai (CST, +0800)
     NTP enabled: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
      DST active: n/a
```

At this moment, the time display on panel is UTC, only after a while(about 10 minutes), the `NTP synchronized` will eventually change to `yes`, then I have CST on the panel. So how can I force the NTP sync as soon as booting?

Comment: Might be helpful: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_Time_Protocol_daemon#Synchronize_once_per_boot

Comment: @slm, it doesn't work, I tried to manually start the daemon after booting, nothing happened, it seems I still have to wait.

Answer (score 0):

Add iburst to the server line in ntp.conf. Your ntp.conf will have one or more lines that look like:

```
server tick.example.com
server tock.example.com
```

Add iburst to the end of each line. After the change they should looke like:

```
server tick.example.com iburst
server tock.example.com iburst
```

then reset ntp